# TNS Issue, Only oracle.msc service not available

Tags: oracle, tns

I am getting the same problem of TNS error. To resolve it, I have check my oracle services. So, out of 4, only 3 services are there. The main oracle.msc is not there.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6lt1.png)
So, how can i start this service

Comment: I can't read your mind or peek your monitor so I don't really know what you're talking about but, if you are running Oracle on Windows, I can tell you that there isn't a dedicated app in Microsoft Management Console format. You should see some dedicated icons in Start menu (which basically point to some *.bat files).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question doesn't really fit SO's Q&A format, and it is also off-topic on SO (since it's not about programming). Please re-read the FAQ.